# Opening MongoDB database

Tags: javascript, linux, mongodb

I have what appears to be MongoDB database files in a directory db-data.The files are named in a way that makes sense that there are records inside. The files are created programmatically by our test automation suite. I am only starting, so have no clue what's going on.
One of the tests is failing. I want to execute the query directly, to see what's happening and eventually fix the test. I installed MongoDB tools, and want to figure out how to connect to this database.

Currently, mongo(1) sees only the default 'test' database. Please advise.

Thank you

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question, but if you want to switch DBs in the mongo shell, type `use <dbName>`

Comment: I know how to switch databases from mongo(1). I want mongo to understand that data files in a particular directory are from a database, so I can connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use terminal to show database & data info. If you have database then just write : user . If you want to show all database then just write : show dbs. Then you can write all query on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You should just read the manual. It's pretty straight forward.

[MongoDB Manual](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/)

Go to your `<mongodb installation dir>`:

```
cd <mongodb installation dir>
```

Type `./bin/mongo` to start mongo:

```
./bin/mongo
```

To display the database you are using, type `db`:

```
db
```

The operation should return test, which is the default database. To switch databases, issue the `use <db>` helper, as in the following example:

```
use <database>
```